# ActionBar Sherlock styling issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working on a new application on android.I have implemented actionbarsherlock in my app .
This is the screenshot of my screen.[image: image1]

I want to change the background of the screen so i created a style.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
<item name="background">#ffff0000</item>
   </style>
```

After using my theme the blue border is missing.
This is the screen i got after using my theme.[image].

Please help me to find me a solution friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because the blue border is part of the actionbar background. When you changed it to red it disappeared.

You have to create your own drawable with a bottom border and override the actionbar's background.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any previous experience with Sherlock, but I see in your style you have a background attribute:

```
<item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
```

So, I believe you could make a custom background with a red color and a border at the bottom, let it be a [shape](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/drawing-shapes-in-android/), or a 9 patch image for example.

And then you could set it like this:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_cool_background</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

That blue line border is a part of a background drawable. See file res/drawable-hdpi/abs__cab_background_top_holo_dark.9.png.
So if you want a bottom line border in your actionbar with a custom background, you need to create a 9-patch drawable with that border.

Answer (score 1):

In file layout/abs__action_bar_tab_bar_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@drawable/bq_up_bar"
/>
<!--   style="?attr/actionBarTabBarStyle"  -->
```